# How to get promise's returned value in JS?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

This is my async function:

```
const returnNumberOfFoods = async() => {


  const web3 = new Web3(url);
  // const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
  const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(
    Contract.abi,
    Contract.address
  );

  let result;
  await myContract.methods.numberOfFoods().call(function(err, res) {
    result = res;
  });
  return result;
}
```

And this is how I am trying to get value:

```
const numberOfCardsPromise = returnNumberOfFoods();

const numberOfCards = numberOfCardsPromise.then(value => { return value; });
console.log(numberOfCards);
```

But this is what I get in console:

```
Promise {<pending>}
    [[Prototype]]: Promise
    [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
    [[PromiseResult]]: "4"
```

The `PromiseResult` is my desired output.

Comment: Please see [How do I return the response from an aynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/438992), which this duplicates.

Comment: You are trying to mix asynchronous and synchronous code, which is not possible in a simple way. In fact, the whole point of asynchronous code is to run separately. To see it in the console, try putting in `numberOfCardsPromise.then(value => {console.log(value)})`. If you need to work with the variable itself, then work with it _within_ the `then` declaration.

Comment: What is `numberOfFoods`? What is `call` -- is it the native `Function#call`?

Comment: @trincot this is from a ethereum smart contract call

Comment: Could you provide the link to the documentation for these methods? What do they return as data type?

Comment: @trincot https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-contract.html#id31 please have a look.

Comment: The question has been closed.

Comment: Check out my answer - I added some code snippets to demonstrate what I'm trying to explain. Essentially, the rule of thumb is to not mix `async` and `sync` code until you understand exactly how it works. An example of 'mixing' could be threading, where you are trying to run multiple operations parallelly (though service workers would be better for that, which by the way are also asynchronous).

Answer (score 1):

Have 2 ways:

First:

```js
const numberOfCards = await returnNumberOfFoods();
```

Second:

```js
returnNumberOfFoods().then((return) => {
   console.log(return);
});
```

Comment: Just a few suggestions - firstly, you don't need your 'first' step, the second step itself will suffice. Secondly, try not to use `return` as a variable as that is a special keyword that might cause problems.

Comment: This answer does not solve the Asker's problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve your problem. However, mixing synchronous and asynchronous code is not one of them.

A potential solution would be to work with the `then` statement:

```js
async function test(){
  return true
}

test().then(value => {
console.log(JSON.stringify(value) + " (I'm asynchronous!)") //works
})
console.log(test()) //doesn't work, returns unfulfilled promise
```

You can also declare another await statement - but note that this has to be inside another `async` function, as synchronous code will not 'pause' until the value is defined.

```js
async function test(){
  return true
}

async function logValueAsync(){
  value = await test()
  console.log(JSON.stringify(value) + " (I'm asynchronous!)") //works
}


function logValueSync(){
  value = test() //await actually generates an error as it is in a synchronous function
  console.log(value) //doesn't work, returns unfulfilled promise
}

logValueAsync()
logValueSync()
```

Note that while it may show that the sync code returns `{}`, in reality it is a promise. You can run this in your browser console to see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the value:

```
const numberOfCards = await returnNumberOfFoods();
console.log(numberOfCards) // desired result
```

Comment: The `await` statement won't do anything - it will still print the same way in the console.

Comment: Sure there is reason for a downvote, @naxsi. This answer doesn't solve the problem. It is clear it hasn't been tested with the rest of the Asker's code